# How to write variable with multiple css properties in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I'm learner of Sass, and want to include border radius of 25px with browser compatibility but getting error. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
$red: #F00;

$border-radius: 
            -webkit-border-radius:25px; 
               -moz-border-radius:25px; 
                    border-radius:25px;
```

```html
h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
 border-radius: $border-radius;
 background: $red;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using a **mixin**. Here's an example from the [Mixin section](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6):

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
h5 {
    @include border-radius(25px);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: $red;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can **also define one class and use that class in h5**:

```
.borderClass{
   -webkit-border-radius:25px; 
   -moz-border-radius:25px; 
   border-radius:25px;
 }

h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: $red;
  @extend .borderClass
}
```